# Upgrade to 11.10 fails on Flash

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I tried to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 this morning and the upgrade failed. First, it reported a flash error and then at the very end it aborted the upgrade due to these same flash errors.

I have read the flash failure was due to my running in wireless mode. The questions are:

Do I need to restore back to 11.04 and how do I do that?

Or, should I just wait for some kind of update from Ubuntu to resolve any issues that may have resulted?

11.10 seems to be running fine, but without flash and who knows what else.

Comment: Do you have the 64bit OS and the 32bit flash?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem ; in my case, the updater complained of errors, but every other package updated fine. If the update has completed and you're now on 11.10, it seems the same is true for you too.

All you need to do is reinstall the flash plugin once you have an internet connection. Try searching for "flash" in the Ubuntu Software Centre, remove the plugin and then install it again. Once the installation is complete, you'll probably need to restart your browser for flash to start working.

Comment: +1, exactly what I encountered. That was the only problem that I could find with the upgrade, and it was due to my wireless dropping somewhere during the upgrade.